# How to re-enable a disabled dropdownlist & how to clear textbox data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following html inside ym asp.net mvc web application:-

```
<span class="f">Customer Name</span>

<select data-val="true" data-val-length="The field CustomerName must be a string with a maximum length of 50." data-val-length-max="50" data-val-required="The CustomerName field is required." id="FirewallCustomer_CustomerName" name="FirewallCustomer.CustomerName"><option value="">Choose...</option>
//code goes here…
</select>

<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="FirewallCustomer.CustomerName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>

<div>
<span class="f">VLANS</span>

<select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field CustomerVLANSID must be a number." data-val-required="The CustomerVLANSID field is required." id="FirewallCustomer_CustomerVLANSID" name="FirewallCustomer.CustomerVLANSID"><option value="">Choose..</option>
</select>

<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="FirewallCustomer.CustomerVLANSID" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

<div>
<span class="f">VLAN IP</span> <input disabled="disabled" id="VLANIP" name="VLANIP" type="text" value="" />
</div>

<div><span class="f">VLAN Sub NET Mask</span> <input disabled="disabled" id="Subnetmask" name="Subnetmask" type="text" value="" />
</div>
</div>
```

I have the following Script

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#FirewallCustomer_CustomerVLANSID").attr("disabled", "disabled");


        $("#FirewallCustomer_CustomerName").change(function () {
            var idDC = $(this).val();
            var select = $("#FirewallCustomer_CustomerVLANSID");

             $("VLANIP").val('');
            $("Subnetmask").val('');
            select.empty();

       $("#SFirewallCustomer_CustomerVLANSID").removeAttr("disabled");
            $.getJSON("/Firewall/LoadVLANSByCustomerName", { customername: idDC },

            function (VLANData) {

                select.append($('<option/>', {
                    value: null
                }));
                $.each(VLANData, function (index, itemData) {

                    select.append($('<option/>', {
                        value: itemData.Value,
                        text: itemData.Text
                    }));
                });
            });
        });

});
```

but I am facing the following probems:-

1. The drop down list will not be re-ebabled

   $("#SFirewallCustomer_CustomerVLANSID").removeAttr("disabled");
2. And the

   $("VLANIP").val('');

   $("Subnetmask").val('');

Will not clear the text.

Can anyone advice what is the problem ?
Thanks

Comment: depending jq version you are using, you should use `.prop('disabled',true)` and `.prop('disabled',false)`

Comment: but i was able to disabled it in the fitst line of my script file, but i was not able to re-enabled it ? and i am using 1.8.2 javascript version.

Comment: ya, don't remove attribute, set it to false using `.prop()` as prefered method

Comment: ok i change it but "prop('disabled',true)" will disable , while prop('disabled',false) will not re-enable it ... so i am having the same problem. any adive ?

Comment: `.prop('disabled',false)` should re-enable it

Comment: but it did not work ,, i tried it on firefox, ie and chrome ,,

Comment: so, you are making a mistake somewhere else, here a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/2Rcv2/

Comment: maybe the problem is related to the html.dropdownlistfor() template which i am using to produce my markup ...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$("#FirewallCustomer_CustomerVLANSID").attr("disabled", "disabled");` and `$("#SFirewallCustomer_CustomerVLANSID").removeAttr("disabled");` use

```
$("#FirewallCustomer_CustomerVLANSID").prop("disabled", true);
```

and

```
$("#FirewallCustomer_CustomerVLANSID").prop("disabled", false);
```

You forgot to add id selector `#`

```
$("#VLANIP").val('');
$("#Subnetmask").val('');
```

Comment: $("#FirewallCustomer_CustomerVLANSID").prop("disabled", true); will disabled it ,,, but $("#FirewallCustomer_CustomerVLANSID").prop("disabled", false); will not re-enable it ...

Comment: Maybe because you empty() it before? Which I think is not good.